# hide database location from title bar in microsoft office access 2013

Tags: office-2013

In microsoft office access 2013, the full path of file location appears in the title bar, how to force access 2013 to show only the file name like the access 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution out on my own:
you can set it manually by clicking on File-> Options -> Current Database, then set the application title.
and you can update the access application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access via C# code as follow:

```
try
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Property p = AccessApplication.CurrentDb().CreateProperty("AppTitle", 10, accessWorkFile.DisplayName);
    AccessApplication.CurrentDb().Properties.Append(p);
    AccessApplication.CurrentDb().Properties.Refresh();
 }
 catch
 {
 }

 AccessApplication.CurrentDb().Properties["AppTitle"].Value = accessWorkFile.DisplayName;
 AccessApplication.RefreshTitleBar();
```